# creat 3d file importer to three.js viewer

Tags: 3d, three.js, stl-format

im trying to creat an app to users can upload their 3d Stl and view them in a Three.js viewer.

somone have any idea from where i can start developing the app in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably start with this example:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_stl